# Using @Rest In Android Annotations to Make Multipart Post

Tags: android, android-annotations, androidhttpclient

I am sending a multipart request to a server which will include an image, as well as a couple of strings.
I haven't found any guide on how to get this done, all i have found are just how to make post and get and put etc, but nothing on multipart.
I would be glad for any help, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/652#issuecomment-20729104) you have a example to do declare it using a @Rest interface and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095020/android-spring-file-upload-outofmemory) you have a example to do it using Spring Android (used by AA to generate the client class)

All together you can use something like this (this code is not tested):

`@Rest(rootUrl = "http://mycompany.com/images", converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class)
public interface RestClient {
    @Post("/loadimage")
    void sendImage(MultiValueMap formfields);
}

@EActivity
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @RestService
    RestClient restClient; //Inject it

    void sendImage(InputStream in) {
        MultiValueMap values = new org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();

        try {
            values.put("fileName", "a.jpg");
            values.put("file", in);
            restClient.sendImage(values);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: The second link pointing to the Spring example isn't a link, can you add the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   String url = "here_your_url";
   File image = new File("here_your_image's_route");

   HttpClient httpClient    = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost        = new HttpPost(url);
```

then:

```
   MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

   multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
   multipartEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(image));

   final HttpEntity requestEntity = multipartEntity.build();

   //You can add more HttpEntity
   httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

   StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
   int statusCode        = statusLine.getStatusCode();

   if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        //everything is correct
   } else {
        //something has gone wrong
   }
```

I use three libraries for that:

- httpcore-4.3.jar
- httpmime-4.3.1.jar
- apache-mime4j-0.4.jar

check that: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi, I think the latter is not here, look elsewhere.